# Center a View with Pixate

Tags: pixate

How would I vertically center a view with Pixate?

If I was styling a web element I would do something like this:

```
element {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Pixate apparently does not have `margin` but you can use `left` and `right` to specify the position from neighbor elements.

So I thought it could be something like this:

```
element {
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
```

But that does not work. The view stays in the upper left corner of the screen.

Is there a way to do this without using aboslute pixel coordinates which I'd like to avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only ways to dynamically center a view are:

1. Auto Layout constraints
2. Springs and struts (if you're not using Auto Layout)
3. Dynamic, mathematical placement of the view using `CGRect`

I don't believe Pixate offers any view placement options.